# How can I detect when a TCollection has been deleted at design time?

Tags: delphi, list, delphi-xe

I have a visual component that needs to detect when a collection item has been deleted so it can re-paint.

TCollection has the following protected procedure:

```
procedure Notify(Item: TCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification); virtual;
```

Unfortunately it is only called when an item is added and just **before** it is deleted. I need to know when an item has been **deleted**.

Internally, TCollection uses a TList that also provides a Notify procedure. The TList version **does** include a Deleted notification. Unfortunately, the TList is a private member.

How can I detect when a TCollection item has been deleted?

Comment: Could you post yourself a message in the before delete event to trigger a repaint?

Comment: Overriding the collections `Update` method might do the job too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TCollection.Notify()` is the correct way to go.  Simply don't repaint immediately, `Invalidate()` the component instead.  By the time the next repaint is actually triggered, the removed item will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

Override the collection item's `SetCollection` method. Implement it something like this:

```
procedure TFooCollectionItem.SetCollection(const Value: TCollection);
var
  OldCollection: TFooCollection;
begin
  OldCollection := Collection as TFooCollection;
  inherited;
  if (OldCollection <> Value) and Assigned(OldCollection) then
    OldCollection.NotifyItemReallyRemoved(Self);
end;
```

You can provide and implement the hypothetical `NotifyItemReallyRemoved` method yourself.

Comment: It may work, but it is not the correct answer.  Using `TCollection.Notify()` is the correct answer.